# ENUM types and usage in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, enums

if I wrote like this:

```
typedef enum {
  foo_1,
  foo_2
}foo ;
```

I found that I can use

`int footype = foo::foo_1` in c++

and  I can directly use

`int footype = foo_1` in c,

so is there a way that can write same code that works both in c++ and c? the code is inside   one  header file with only one structure.

Comment: Just use `foo_1` without the namespace, it should work in both, althougt you have to declare `using namespace foo` for c++

Comment: @h3nr1x foo is not a namespace and no need to declare it in C++.

Comment: @icepack yes, you're right, I missreaded the question and obviated the `foo` after the `typedef`, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int footype = foo_1;
```

That will compile in both C and C++.

```
int footype = foo::foo_1;
```

This syntax is only necessary for C++11's strongly typed enums.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
int footype = foo::foo_1
```

is legal only in C++11. In C++03 an enumeration is not a scope and this is illegal, just like in C. In C++11 there are two types of enums - ordinary C-like enums, and scoped enums, declared with

```
 enum class
```

For the latter, the enumerator qualification(`::`) is mandatory. For the former - optional.

So, using simply

```
int footype foo = foo_1;
```

will work in all C, C++03 and C++11

Comment: It looks suspiciously like you didn't read the question... this is about writing code that is compatible with C and C++ (for use in header files).

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with dropping the typedef it should "just work"

```
enum {
    foo_1,
    foo_2
};

int
main(void)
{
    int foo = foo_1;

    return 0;
}
```

That compiles for me with both gcc and g++

```
g++ --std=c++03 enum.cc -o enum_cpp
gcc --std=c99 enum.c -o enum_c
```

Comment: Having the `typedef` there is not an issue

Comment: Make it `gcc -Wall ...`/`g++ -Wall ...`.